# Python Pandas Sum Values in Columns If date between 2 dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, melt

I have a dataframe `df` which can be created with this:

```
data={'id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
      'date1':[datetime.date(2016,1,1),datetime.date(2016,1,2),datetime.date(2016,1,3),datetime.date(2016,1,4),
               datetime.date(2016,1,2),datetime.date(2016,1,4),datetime.date(2016,1,3),datetime.date(2016,1,1)],
      'date2':[datetime.date(2016,1,5),datetime.date(2016,1,3),datetime.date(2016,1,5),datetime.date(2016,1,5),
               datetime.date(2016,1,4),datetime.date(2016,1,5),datetime.date(2016,1,4),datetime.date(2016,1,1)],
      'score1':[5,7,3,2,9,3,8,3],
      'score2':[1,3,0,5,2,20,7,7]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

And looks like this:
   id       date1       date2  score1  score2
0   1  2016-01-01  2016-01-05       5       1
1   1  2016-01-02  2016-01-03       7       3
2   1  2016-01-03  2016-01-05       3       0
3   1  2016-01-04  2016-01-05       2       5
4   2  2016-01-02  2016-01-04       9       2
5   2  2016-01-04  2016-01-05       3      20
6   2  2016-01-03  2016-01-04       8       7
7   2  2016-01-01  2016-01-01       3       7
```

What I need to do is create a column for each of `score1` and `score2`, which creates two columns which SUM the values of `score1` and `score2` respectively, based on whether the `usedate` is between `date1` and `date2`. `usedate` is created by getting all dates between and including the `date1` minimum and the `date2` maximum.  I used this to create the date range:

```
drange=pd.date_range(df.date1.min(),df.date2.max())
```

The resulting dataframe `newdf` should look like:

```
     usedate  score1sum  score2sum
0 2016-01-01          8          8
1 2016-01-02         21          6
2 2016-01-03         32         13
3 2016-01-04         30         35
4 2016-01-05         13         26
```

For clarification, on `usedate` 2016-01-01, `score1sum` is 8, which is calculated by looking at the rows in `df` where 2016-01-01 is between and including `date1` and `date2`, which sum row0(5) and row8(3).  On `usedate` 2016-01-04, `score2sum` is 35, which is calculated by looking at the rows in `df` where 2016-01-04 is between and including `date1` and `date2`, which sum row0(1), row3(0), row4(5), row5(2), row6(20), row7(7).

Maybe some kind of `groupby`, or `melt` then `groupby`?

Comment: Do you count rows from 0 or 1? There is a confusion in your second example. And in the first example I don't see that row8 is 3. Back to second example, how come `2016-01-04` is between `2017-05-28 and 2017-09-22`, and between `2015-11-01 and 2015-11-09`?

Comment: Also, your minimum date (`df.date1.min()`) is `2015-11-01`, how can your `usedate` column start from `2016-01-01`?

Comment: @Fatih Akici, much apologies.  I had recreated the sample dataframe with fewer dates, and forgot to change what I originally had.  I have updated the question with the correct sample.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `apply` with lambda function:

```
df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date1'])

df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date2'])

df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(df.date1.min(), df.date2.max()), columns = ['score1sum', 'score2sum'])

df1[['score1sum','score2sum']] = df1.apply(lambda x: df.loc[(df.date1 <= x.name) & 
                                                            (x.name <= df.date2),
                                                            ['score1','score2']].sum(), axis=1)

df1.rename_axis('usedate').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
     usedate  score1sum  score2sum
0 2016-01-01          8          8
1 2016-01-02         21          6
2 2016-01-03         32         13
3 2016-01-04         30         35
4 2016-01-05         13         26
```

Comment: what is the x.name above referring to?

Comment: x.name is refering to the column the apply is working on.  Apply takes each column of a dataframe at a time.  Determine which  column are you are working you can use x.name to that series name.

Comment: im confused, can you please apply the actual column name you used to get the output?  I assumed your code would apply to both score1 and score2.

Comment: I am sorry.... since we are using apply with axis=1, x.name is referring the row index of the dataframe we are working on.     So, for row1 x.name will be the first date in the index.  Apply works on a column or a row at time time depending on the axis.  So, each of those are passed in as 'pd.Series' with the index as the name.

Comment: No.  x.name in this case is referring to the usedate we are building in the dataframe.   So when you apply with axis=1. Each row is passed in as a series, the series index are the column headers from the dataframe and the name of the series is the row index of that dataframe.

Comment: this works, choosing this but want to see if the below is faster, waiting on @Peter Leimbigler to respond to using transform with a series...

Answer (score 1):

#### Method 1: list comprehensions

This is inelegant, but hey, it works! (EDIT: added a second method below.)

```
# Convert datetime.date to pandas timestamps for easier comparisons
df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date1'])
df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date2'])

# solution
newdf = pd.DataFrame(data=drange, columns=['usedate'])
# for each usedate ud, get all df rows whose dates contain ud,
# then sum the scores of these rows
newdf['score1sum'] = [df[(df['date1'] <= ud) & (df['date2'] >= ud)]['score1'].sum() for ud in drange]
newdf['score2sum'] = [df[(df['date1'] <= ud) & (df['date2'] >= ud)]['score2'].sum() for ud in drange]

# output
newdf
     usedate  score1sum  score2sum
  2016-01-01          8          8
  2016-01-02         21          6
  2016-01-03         32         13
  2016-01-04         30         35
  2016-01-05         13         26
```

#### Method 2: a helper function with `transform` (or `apply`)

```
newdf = pd.DataFrame(data=drange, columns=['usedate'])

def sum_scores(d):
    return df[(df['date1'] <= d) & (df['date2'] >= d)][['score1', 'score2']].sum()

# apply works here too, and is about equally fast in my testing
newdf[['score1sum', 'score2sum']] = newdf['usedate'].transform(sum_scores)

# newdf is same to above
```

#### Timings are comparable

```
# Jupyter timeit cell magic
%%timeit 
newdf['score1sum'] = [df[(df['date1'] <= d) & (df['date2'] >= d)]['score1'].sum() for d in drange]
newdf['score1sum'] = [df[(df['date1'] <= d) & (df['date2'] >= d)]['score2'].sum() for d in drange]

100 loops, best of 3: 10.4 ms per loop

# Jupyter timeit line magic
%timeit newdf[['score1sum', 'score2sum']] = newdf['usedate'].transform(sum_scores) 

100 loops, best of 3: 8.51 ms per loop
```

Comment: when I run this I get'Series Object has no attribute 'transform'.  newdf['usedate'] is a series.  How did you get the transform to work?

Comment: @clg4 I think you need to upgrade your pandas?  What version of pandas are running?

Comment: Pandas version 19.2

Comment: @clg4, that's it: [`DataFrame.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) was introduced in 0.20.0.

Comment: in this answer, you have `date=drange` what is drange?

Comment: From OP's question: `drange=pd.date_range(df.date1.min(),df.date2.max())`

Answer (score 0):

[conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.conditional_join.html#janitor.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) may be helpful in the abstraction/convenience:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor as jn

drange = pd.DataFrame(drange, columns=['dates'])
df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date1'])
df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date2'])

(drange.conditional_join(df, 
                         ('dates', 'date1', '>='), 
                         ('dates', 'date2', '<='))
.droplevel(0, 1)
.select_columns('dates', 'score*')
.groupby('dates')
.sum()
.add_suffix('num')
) 
            score1num  score2num
dates                           
2016-01-01          8          8
2016-01-02         21          6
2016-01-03         32         13
2016-01-04         30         35
2016-01-05         13         26
```